# Do I need to release a connection if I throw an error?

Tags: mysql, exception, error-handling, using-statement, try-catch-finally

So if I get a connection pool, then something unexpected happens and the error will be thrown, do I need to additionally release a connection? What happens with the MySQL connection pool once the error is thrown?

Comment: What programming language? What library are you using to implement the connection pool?

Comment: *and the error will be thrown* What kind of error?

Comment: I am using node.js with mysql2 module.

Comment: @Akina i am using if(error) throw error; line, so this can be anything honestly. Since throw stops the method from executing, I need info if the connection is not released by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell us what programming language you use, or what sort of exception you want to catch. So it's hard to be specific.

In general, the answer is **yes**.  Always release / dispose / deallocate any resources like connections and cursors. These sorts of resources are sometimes called *serially reusable resources*. If you don't release them they'll eventually become used up and your program will stop working. If you're lucky it will crash. If you're unlucky it will just hang waiting for a resource that will never arrive.

Some languages use the `try {} catch() {} finally {}` pattern to release resources whenever allocated. Put your connection release code in the `finally{}` block, and it will always run.

C# uses `using (var resource = getSomeResource()) {}`.  This pattern ensures the resource's `.dispose()` method is always invoked even if the code in the block throws an exception.

The more care you take with this, the longer your program will run without crashing due to some kind of resource leak. The language constructs I mentioned were invented precisely to solve your problem robustly.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!